# Is there an example such that $\text{rank}(A^t)\neq \text{rank}(A)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, examples-counterexamples

Let $R$ be a commutative Noetherian ring and $A\in M_{n\times m}(R)$.

If $R$ is a field, then $rank(A^t)=rank(A)$.

However, in general Noetherian rings, does $rank(A^t)=rank(A)$ hold?

Since the usual proof technique for proving it in the context of a field cannot be applied to a Noetherian ring, I wonder whether this is true or not. (The usual technique assumes $R$ is a division ring)

What is a counterexample? And if this is indeed true, how do I prove it?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "rank" over a general nontrivial commutative ring. You can try generalizing various definitions of a "rank", but their generalizations will be non-equivalent.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I'm taking the standard one. That is, the "rank" of the image of $A$ as an $R$-module homomorphism.

Comment: @Rubertos Your "definition" has no meaning for commutative rings. Image of $A$ is a submodule of $R^n$, but isn't free to have rank.

Comment: @user26857 You are absolutely right. I was foolish.. So I will edit my post to a Noetherian ring